# When using GroupBy in linq, how can I get a list of group names?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda

If the original collection has objects with property prop:

```
prop = "a";
prop = "a";
prop = "b";
prop = "b";
prop = "c";
```

and I'm grouping by prop, I need the output:

```
List<string>{ "a", "b", "c" }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eg.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

following code to group:

```
var foos = new List<Foo>();
var groupings = from foo in foos
                group foo by foo.PropertyA
                into groupedFoos
                select groupedFoos;
/*
// the same as
var groupings = foos.GroupBy(foo => foo.PropertyA);
*/
var keys = from grouping in groupings
           select grouping.Key;
```

`.GroupBy()` will return [`IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx)

if you just want the distinct properties, you can still go for `.Distinct()`, eg:

```
var keys = (from foo in foos
            select foo.PropertyA).Distinct();
```

Comment: I did this: foos.GroupBy(f => f.PropertyA).Select(gr => gr.Key) based on your answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATED

My original answer of using Disticnt() alone is insufficient.  You need to GroupBy the *prop* value, and then select the first member of each subset:

```
myList.GroupBy(i => i.prop).Select(i => i.First()).ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i.prop + ", "));
```

### Demo code

Here's some code that illustrates the groupings.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myList = new List<Foo>() { 
                new Foo(){ prop = "a", anotherProp = "z"},
                new Foo(){ prop = "a", anotherProp = "x"},
                new Foo(){ prop = "b", anotherProp = "x"},
                new Foo(){ prop = "b", anotherProp = "y"},
                new Foo(){ prop = "c", anotherProp = "z"}
            };

            // Display groups.
            myList.GroupBy(i => i.prop).ToList().ForEach(j =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t");
                j.ToList().ForEach(k => Console.Write(k.prop + ", "));
            });

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 25));

            // Display desired output.
            myList.GroupBy(i => i.prop).Select(i => i.First()).ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i.prop + ", "));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    public class Foo
    {
        public string prop { get; set; }
        public string anotherProp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: you **do not** need to select the first item of each grouping. it would be way more elegant if you use the property `Key` of the group to retrieve the wanted value!

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer:

```
stuff.GroupBy(e => e.prop).Select(group => group.Key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using group by only gives individual items by your comparison function. if the comparison is done by `prop` it will return the objects with distinct `prop` only. all you need to do is iterate over them and select only `prop`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<strings> groups context.YourObjects.Select(o => o.prop).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = from a in yourList 
group a by a.prop into b
select b.Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyClass> source = getSource();

List<IGrouping<KeyType, MyClass>> groups = source
  .GroupBy(x => x.prop)
  .ToList();

List<KeyType> keys = groups
  .Select(g => g.Key)
  .ToList();
```